# setInterval using loops

Tags: javascript

I wrote code that changes images every 3 seconds using loops, and the problem is the loop is so fast that the picture jumps to the last picture instead of going one by one. Can this be easily solved?

The code is:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <img src="Images/london.jpg" id="london" height="450" width="450" /> <input type="button" onclick="changeTimer()" value="Start" />
  </div>
</form>
<script>
  function changeTimer() {
    setInterval(function () { changeImage() }, 3000);
  }
  var pictures = new Array("Images/moscow.jpg", "Images/pariz.jpg", "Images/Roma.jpg");
  var i;

  function changeImage() {
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        document.getElementById("london").src = pictures[i];
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Remove the `for` loop in `changeImage`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var i=0;
```

and

```
function changeImage() {         
            document.getElementById("london").src = pictures[i];
            i = (i==pictures.length-1) ? 0 : i++; 
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't loop back to 0 when it runs out of pictures.

Comment: I think you're gonna have an off-by-one here

Answer (score 0):

this code would be ok!

```
function changeTimer() {
    setInterval(function () { changeImage() }, 3000);
}
var pictures = new Array("Images/moscow.jpg", "Images/pariz.jpg", "Images/Roma.jpg");
var i=0;
function changeImage() {
    document.getElementById("london").src = pictures[i];
    i = (i+1)%3;
}
```

Comment: Instead of hard-coding `3`, use `pictures.length`

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <img src="Images/london.jpg" id="london" height="450" width="450" /> <input type="button" onclick="changeTimer()" value="Start" />
    </div>
</form>


 <script>
    var i=0;
    function changeTimer() {
        setInterval(function() {
            changeImage()
        }, 3000);
    }
    var pictures = new Array("Images/moscow.jpg", "Images/pariz.jpg", "Images/Roma.jpg");


    function changeImage() {

        document.getElementById("london").src = pictures[i];
        i++;
        if (i == 3) {
            i = 0;
        }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
function rotateImages() {
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function () { 
        document.getElementById("london").src = pictures[i++];
        i = (i == pictures.length) ? 0 : i;
    }, 3000);
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JKgY3/4/)